# storing express "res" variable and using it later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a simple nodeJs server with express and I have an external module that handles sending the response to the requests. In order for this file to work, it needs to access express `res` variable. Before, I used to send this variable to the module functions to use it, but then I tried to use a middleware to store this variable in the module and not send it every time I'm calling a function, and ***it worked!*** 
This is the code:

```
// app.js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var response = require('./response.js');

// store the value of 'res' in the response module
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    response.setRes(res);
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    response.success("Welcome");                  // works fine
});

app.get("/images", function(req, res){
    response.forbidded("Forbidded");              // works fine
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening... ");
});
```

and this is the other module

```
// response.js
exports.setRes = function(_res){
    res = _res;
};

exports.success = function(msg){
    res.status(200).send(msg);
};

exports.forbidded = function(msg){
    res.status(403).send(msg);
};
```

My question is: 
Is this a good approach? and will this affect my application if the number of users increases (*I'm worried that one user might get the `res` of another user*)

Comment: That is not a good approach for exactly the reason you wrote. Make middleware to add `success`/`forbidden` to `res` instead or something.

Comment: Your fear is warranted. It looks like you have one global `res` value, so yes, different users will collide. This should be easy enough to verify... put a `setTimeout` somewhere to delay the response, and then try to make two requests in two different tabs in your browser.

Comment: I see that, I tried it and it conflicted, thank you very much.

Comment: Do sth like *res.custom=new response(res);* to implement it just for the current request